# Is it possible to access a field value in one collection from another collection in firestore?

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore

Is it possible to access/pass field value(in this case gamerroomname) of Allusers collection from/to another collection(in this case gamerooms)?

so that I can do below:

```
ref.collection("GameRooms").document(gameroomname).addSnapshotListener(){
}
```

Screenshot of Allusers:
[image]

Screenshot of Gamerooms:

[image]

After trying,the below code works.But is this the correct way to do this or is there any way better:

```js
 mFirestore.collection("AllUsers").document(SplitString(currentUser.email!!)).get().addOnSuccessListener(OnSuccessListener<DocumentSnapshot> { documentSnapshot ->
            var gameRoomName: String = ""
            if (documentSnapshot.exists()) {
                gameRoomName = documentSnapshot.getString("gameroomname")!!
            }
            mFirestore.collection("GameRooms").document(gameRoomName).collection("Words called").addSnapshotListener(EventListener<QuerySnapshot>(){ queryDocumentSnapshot, e->
                selectedWordsList.clear()
                if (!queryDocumentSnapshot!!.isEmpty) {
                    val gameRoomList = queryDocumentSnapshot.documents
                    for (doc: DocumentSnapshot in gameRoomList) {
                        var addWord: String = ""
                        if (doc.get("addword") != null) {
                            addWord = doc.get("addword").toString()
                        }
                        val selectedGameRoomList: SelectedWordsObject = SelectedWordsObject(addWord, false)
                        selectedWordsList.add(selectedGameRoomList)
                        mSelectedWordsAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
                    }
                    mSelectedWordsAdapter.notifyItemChanged(0)
                }
                else {
                    Toast.makeText(this@Screen, "Document does not exist", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
                }
            })
        }).addOnFailureListener(OnFailureListener { e->
            val error=e.message
            Toast.makeText(this@Screen,"Error:"+error, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
        })
```

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong, You want to pass the gameroomname value of All Documents present in AllUsers Collection to a Collection of GameRooms?? If that's what you are looking for Which document are you willing to pass to in GameRooms Collection??

Comment: @Fire-In-D-Hole On click  I want to get current users gameroomname value from Allusers and then pass that field value to Gamerooms in order to find the same gameroom doc .I have attached image of gamerooms too above.Did I make it understandable?

Comment: Yes, that sounds possible. What is the problem you currently have with this? Note that it's much more likely someone can help if you provide the *minimal* code that reproduces where you are stuck. See [how to create a minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Earlier I could not understand what to do .But after trying a bit,the above code works for me,but is it the right way of doing it?

Comment: Looks fine at first glance. You'll want to move the `mFirestore.collection("GameRooms").document(gameRoomName).collection("Words called").addSnapshotListener(...` **into** the `if` block above it though, because it now also runs when the document doesn't exist and `gameRoomName` is just `""`.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen ok,i will do that.Thanks :-)